# Perl: What is the meaning of "Could not read metadata file"?

Tags: perl, cpan

On updating my Perl installation on several Debian and Ubuntu servers, I noticed that some of them print out the line "Could not read metadata file" at the end:

```
# perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bundle::CPAN'
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.20)
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Wed, 05 Mar 2014 13:06:14 GMT
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v0.90)
Reading 53 yaml files from /root/.cpan/build/
CPAN: Time::HiRes loaded ok (v1.9719)
................................DONE
Restored the state of none (in 0.9880 secs)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v2.18)
ExtUtils::MakeMaker is up to date (6.90).
Test::Harness is up to date (3.30).
ExtUtils::CBuilder is up to date (0.280212).
File::Temp is up to date (0.2304).
Test::More is up to date (1.001002).
Data::Dumper is up to date (2.145).
IO::Compress::Base is up to date (2.064).
Compress::Zlib is up to date (2.064).
IO::Zlib is up to date (1.10).
Archive::Tar is up to date (1.96).
Module::Build is up to date (0.4205).
File::Spec is up to date (3.40).
Digest::SHA is up to date (5.87).
File::HomeDir is up to date (1.00).
Archive::Zip is up to date (1.37).
Net::FTP is up to date (2.79).
Term::ReadKey is up to date (2.31).
Term::ReadLine::Perl is up to date (1.0303).
YAML is up to date (0.90).
Parse::CPAN::Meta is up to date (1.4414).
Text::Glob is up to date (0.09).
CPAN is up to date (2.00).
File::Which is up to date (1.09).
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.120351)
Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
```

I googled, but couldn´t find anything helpful. Guessing that this is nothing I would need to worry about, I am still interested in what this actually means (and how I can get rid of it).

Answer (score 2):

Perl modules that are packaged according to CPAN convention include a mile named META.yml or META.json - the metadata file, which among other things defines a list of prerequisites for building and testing the module.

You'll have to read the code of the CPAN client (thanks tobyink) to find out when/why it would produce that exact error message.

RETRACTED (see below): So either the module in question did not have one, or had a malformed one.  You'll have to read the code of the build tools (usually Module::Builder or ExtUtils) to find out when/why it would produce that exact error message.

Comment: Actually that warning [comes from the CPAN client](https://metacpan.org/source/ANDK/CPAN-2.00/lib/CPAN/Distribution.pm#L3006); not from Makefile.PL or Build.PL. (Makefile.PL and Build.PL don't usually need to *read* the metadata file - they typically *write* it.)

Comment: Thx, this takes me a step further. Though, I couldn´t find out, what part of the code might trigger the function in question to return false. The warning seems to stem from CPAN::Meta.

Comment: Welcome to the Perl Debugger. Would you like a beverage :-).  It its a system that I can manipulate all I like, I'll set a breakpoint in the CPAN module, at the error, and then start poking around and looking at my stack and stepping through code.  I learn a lot that way.